# How to get kernel version without arch

Tags: linux, uname

I am looking for a command that will return the kernel build without the architecture.

uname -r returns: 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64 but I only need 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6

I can do this using a regex and chomp everything past the last dot

Comment: You said "I can do this using a regex". It seems you solved it already. So what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how portable it is but you could do the following --

uname -r | sed s/\.`arch`//

example -

$ uname -r

2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64

$ uname -r | sed s/\.`arch`//

2.6.32-358.6.2.el6

Answer (score 0):

Given that regex can be used, you can match the string against `^(.*)\.[^.]*$` and take the first capture group.

(`(.*)\..*` will generally also work, with "greedy" quantifiers, but cf. a reference for your regex engine.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid it. During the kernel build, with the help of "Local version - append to the kernel release" (http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/init/Kconfig#L56) configuration option these extra "el6.x86_64" are set and mainly to track build and release versions.

So, a possible workaround is like below:

```
           uname -a | awk '{print $3}'
```